# I'm getting memory exceptions when loading animation using BitmapFactory

Tags: android, android-asynctask, bitmapfactory, android-glide

I have a 6 images that I load together as an animation, and they are stored in mFrames. The method below prepares these images, before calling a smaller method to load them. I'm getting an OutOfMemoryError sometimes when I try to load them. I load the images in another method with: mImageView.setImageDrawable(mAnimHardRef); mAnimHardRef.start();

```
private void loadAnimationAsync() {
    AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            final AnimationDrawable drawable = new AnimationDrawable();
            drawable.setOneShot(true);
            for(int frRes : mFrames) {
                Bitmap temp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mActivity.getResources(), frRes);
                temp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(temp, temp.getWidth() / 6, temp.getHeight() / 6, false);
                drawable.addFrame(new BitmapDrawable(temp), 60);
            }
            mAnimSoftRef = new SoftReference<AnimationDrawable>(drawable);
            mAnimHardRef = drawable;
            if (mShowAnim) mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (mShowAnim) showAnimationNow();
                }
            });
            Log.d("Joshua", "BG load time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time));
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: `OutOfMemoryError`. `memory exceptions` ??? Where are the exceptions?

Comment: `AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {`  I have never seen such a construct. Does that really work?

Comment: You are first creating a complete bitmap in memory and then you scale it down. You could better scale it down while loading. Needs less memory.